# Two Java application in docker one always killed

Tags: java, docker, hazelcast

I have two java application who are connected via hazelcast:

```
final var clusterPort = 5701;
final var hazelcastConfig = new Config();
hazelcastConfig.setClusterName("alpha-cluster");
hazelcastConfig.setInstanceName(instanceName);
final var networkConfig = hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig();
networkConfig.setPort(5701);
final var joinConfig = networkConfig.getJoin();
joinConfig.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
final var tcpIpConfig = joinConfig.getTcpIpConfig();
tcpIpConfig.setEnabled(true);
for (int port = clusterPort; port < clusterPort + 10; port++) {
        tcpIpConfig.addMember(String.format("%s:%s", this.getHost(), port));
}
return new HazelcastClusterManager(hazelcastConfig);
```

I have following DockerFile

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:latest
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY alpha-api.jar ./alpha-api.jar
COPY alpha-admin-ui.jar ./alpha-admin-ui.jar
COPY start.sh ./start.sh
RUN chmod +x start.sh
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 8081
EXPOSE 5701
EXPOSE 5702
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "start.sh" ]
```

And the ShellScript start.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
CPUS=2
MEMORY=512M
echo "Scripts starts ..."
java -Xmx$MEMORY -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=$CPUS -jar alpha-admin-ui.jar &
java -Xmx$MEMORY -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=$CPUS -jar alpha-api.jar &
wait
```

At first the connections works:

```
2023-10-09 09:38:41 Members {size:2, ver:2} [
2023-10-09 09:38:41     Member [localhost]:5701 - 0b43916b-caca-4f5b-afeb-a0fe696c9283 this
2023-10-09 09:38:41     Member [localhost]:5702 - cb43f74b-7cc2-4e53-9af2-9bdeff5823f7
2023-10-09 09:38:41 ]
```

than later the exception will be thrown:

```
2023-10-09 09:38:43 INFO: [localhost]:5701 [vlab-alpha-cluster] [4.2.7] Could not connect to: localhost/127.0.0.1:5702. Reason: IOException[Connection refused to address localhost/127.0.0.1:5702]
2023-10-09 09:38:43 Oct 09, 2023 7:38:43 AM com.hazelcast.internal.server.tcp.TcpServerConnectionErrorHandler
2023-10-09 09:38:43 WARNING: [localhost]:5701 [vlab-alpha-cluster] [4.2.7] Removing connection to endpoint [localhost]:5702 Cause => java.io.IOException {Connection refused to address localhost/127.0.0.1:5702}, Error-Count: 5
```

So I check in the container and I see the second java application is not running anymore (check via ps aux)
Than I start the second application (alpha-api.jar) again than it works.
So it means the java application process is killed by the OS or  from a different system. I also start the java application directly on my local machine and it runs without any exceptions.

So I thought maybe the memory or CPU is the problem so I add the "-Xmx$MEMORY -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=$CPUS" but nothing changed.
I don't have any idea anymore, why the application is killed silence (the application doesn't stopp by his self).

Add:
I start the start shell script on my local machine and both java applications starts und communicate to each other, so actually is a docker configuration problem or something.

Comment: Is it possible both applications try to connect to the same port `127.0.0.1:5702`? Since the second one does not get it, it would make sense for it to give up and terminate. You can test this by running both applications without docker but on the same machine.

Comment: A standard practice here is to run each application in its own container.  You don't need the script wrapper; you can use Compose `command:` or put a command after the `docker run image-name` to run one or the other of the `java -jar ...` commands.  Since the two containers don't share any code beyond the JVM, building two separate images with a single `CMD` each might be easier.

Comment: @DavidMaze it was planned, but now I want run two jars in one docker image. The reason why I put this in one docker is for the person who just test the application, so he doesn't need compose and different more docker instance.

Comment: @Queeg Hazelcast set the port automatically I cannot set the port directly

Comment: Have you successfully run the two applications on one host machine (not using docker?)

Comment: @Queeg yes on the local machine it running successfully. When I connect to the container and start the java application again with java -jar alpha-api.jar then it works. But it should be working after the docker starts.

Comment: @Qeychon You can set the port. Use `hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig().setPortAutoIncrement(false).setPort(1234);`. If auto-increment is set to true and port 1234 is in use, it'll try 1235, then 1236.... to find an available port. Set it to false and it'll only try to use the port you specify, if it's not free startup fails.

Comment: Logs from the process that shuts down would be helpful. That might indicate why it shut down.